# Should translation change eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

everyone!

I'm working on flow instability and just a newbie. Now, I try to employ spectral method - collocation method to solve Orr-Sommerfeld(OS) equation. I've already solved the eigenvalue problem of Poiseuille flow. And I want to move to Boundary layer instability., during which I come across a problem concerning coordinates transformation. The problem is mainly a mathematical one.

Specificlly, OS equation is as follows.

$$
(U-c)(D^{2}-\alpha^{2})\phi - U^{\prime \prime}\phi = \frac{1}{i \alpha Re} (D^{4}-2\alpha^{2}D^{2}+\alpha^{4})\phi
$$

Mean velocity profile of Poiseuille flow is $U = 1 - x^{2}, -1 <= x <= 1$.

What I concerns is c, wave speed, also eigenvalue. I treat OS equation as a general eigenvalue problem, which leads OS equation to be of the form $A \phi = c B \phi$, where both A and B are operators.

$$
A = \frac{-1}{\alpha Re} (D^4 - 2 \alpha^2 D^2 + \alpha^4) + i U (D^2 - \alpha^2) - i U^{\prime \prime}
$$

$$
B = i (D^2 - \alpha^2)
$$

By some eigenvalue solver, eigenvalues can be solved. Mathematically, eigenvalues are determined by operators A and B. Ok, I finish the above.

Then I consider coordinate transformation. Take a simple example as translation: $y = x + 1$. It translates field from $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ to $0 \leq y \leq 2$. Since the field is translated, operators A and B should be changed to be defined on the new field. Specifically, partial differential operator $D, D^2, D^4$ and velocity profile $U, U^{\prime \prime}$ should be changed. In this case, coordinate transformation is just translation. So, partial differential operator is unchanged and velocity profile becomes $U = -y^2 + 2y, U^{\prime \prime} = -2$. All in all, what changes in this eigenvalue problem $A \phi = c B \phi$ is only velocity profile. It seems operator indeed changes, which results in different eigenvalues from original ones. Then there exists contradiction.

I mean, mathematically, different operators in eigenvalue problem will lead to different eigenvalues. Meanwhile, physically, coordinate translation leads to the same eigenvalues. In fact, I do get same eigenvalues numerically by spectral method - collocation method.

So, where I am wrong from the above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already resolved in the [linked thread](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/main/159439-should-translation-change-eigenvalues.html).  (c.f. OP's self-answer and his first and last comment in the linked thread.)